# How to find if a 3D object fits in another 3D object (the container)?

Tags: algorithm, computational-geometry

Given two 3d objects, how can I find if one fits inside the second (and find the location of the object in the container).

The object should be translated and rotated to fit the container - but not modified otherwise.

Additional complications:

1. The same situation - but look for the best fit solution, even if it's not a proper match (minimize the volume of the object that doesn't fit in the container)
2. Support for elastic objects - find the best fit while minimizing the "distortion" in the objects

This is a pretty general question - and I don't expect a complete solution.
Any pointers to relevant papers \ articles \ libraries \ tools would be useful

Comment: Naive solution: Check all possible pairs of faces for intersections.

Comment: I wasn't clear enough - the 1st object should be moved \ rotated to fit in the container

Comment: Ah.  Then this is complicated!

Comment: Something you need for a realtime approach? Or can it take some time? You could try using bounding boxes: randomizing positions and rotations until you find a match where the boxes do not overlap eachother. If you need more accuracy...well good luck :)

Comment: real time isn't needed. but a bounding box isn't accurate enough.

Comment: Any chance using convex hulls would be helpful? If the shapes are convex, it'd probably be easier to solve.

Comment: Are there any constraints on the container?  Is it always a box, a barrel, any sort of hollow regular solid?  What about the object to be placed? Or are you trying to fit a tommy gun in a violin case?

Comment: The object have a a general shape, and they are expected to fit pretty close to each other

Comment: If they are indeed guaranteed to fit pretty close to each other that helps a lot -- you can then start by aligning centroids, principal axes and so on and get close.  Then some optimization algorithm might work.

Comment: george - looks promising. write it as an answer and it'll be accepted.

Comment: you need to embed the shape in higher dimensions and subtract the embeddings. I will add more details once I am near a desktop machine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one perhaps less than ideal method.

You could try fixing the position (in 3D space) of 1 shape. Placing the other shape on top of that shape. Then create links that connect one point in shape to a point in the other shape. Then simulate what happens when the links are pulled equally tight. Causing the point that isn't fixed to rotate and translate until it's stable.

If the fit is loose enough, you could use only 3 links (the bare minimum number of links for 3D) and try every possible combination. However, for tighter fit fits, you'll need more links, perhaps enough to place them on every point of the shape with the least number of points. Which means you'll some method to determine how to place the links, which is not trivial.

Comment: You assume I know which point in the object should be near a specific point in the container

Comment: And that is why it's less than ideal, as determining that is not easy, hence why you need to try every limited combination. The two methods (the second being using all points of the smaller point) I described require O(N^3) combinations plus whatever it takes to do all of the simulations, and will find fit's that either "loose" (think a square inside of an octagon) or "tight" (think a square inside of a slightly bigger square), but may not work on things in between. Although, I think I might be underestimating the tight fit algorithm, as it might be sufficient by itself.

Comment: Then again, if you've got 100,000+ points, O(N^3) or O(N^2) (bare minimum tight fit), is probably not practical. In which case, hopefully someone knows a better method.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like quite hard problem. Probable approach is to have some heuristic to suggest transformation and than check is it good one. If transformation moves object only slightly out of interior (e.g. on one part) than make slightly adjust to transformation and test it. If object is 'lot' out (e.g. on same/all axis on both sides) than make new heuristic guess.

Just an general idea for a heuristic. Make a rasterisation of an objects with same pixel size. It can be octree of an object volume. Make connectivity graph between pixels. Check subgraph isomorphism between graphs. If there is a subgraph than that position is for a testing.

This approach also supports 90deg rotation(s).

Some tests can be done even on graphs. If all volume neighbours of a subgraph are in larger graph, than object is in.

In general this is 'refined' boundary box approach.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to project equal number of points on both objects and do a least squares best fit on the point sets. The point sets probably will not be ordered the same so iterating between the least squares best fit and a reordering of points so that the points on both objects are close to same order. The equation development for this is a lot of algebra but not conceptually complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Consider one polygon(triangle) in the target object. For this polygon, find the equivalent polygon in the other geometry (source), ie. the length of the sides, angle between the edges, area should all be the same. If there's just one match, find the rigid transform matrix, that alters the vertices that way : `X' = M*X`. Since `X'` AND `X` are known for all the points on the matched polygons, this should be doable with linear algebra.

If you want a one-one mapping between the vertices of the polygon, traverse the edges of the polygons in the same order, and make a lookup table that maps each vertex one one poly to a vertex in another. If you have a [half edge data structure](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/HalfedgeDS/index.html#Chapter_Halfedge_Data_Structures) of your 3d object that'll simplify this process a great deal.

If you find more than one matching polygon, traverse the source polygon from both the points, and keep matching their neighbouring polygons with the target polygons. Continue until one of them breaks, after which you can do the same steps as the one-match version.

There're more serious solutions that're listed [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.173.2196&rep=rep1&type=pdf), but I think the method above will work as well.

Answer (score 0):

What a juicy problem !. As is typical in computational geometry this problem 
can be very complicated with a mismatched geometric abstraction. With all kinds of if-else cases etc.
But pick the right abstraction and the solution becomes trivial with few sub-cases.

Compute the [Distance Transform](https://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/distance.htm) of your shapes and Voilà! Your solution is trivial.
Allow me to elaborate.

The distance map of a shape on a grid (pixels) encodes the distance of the closest point on the
shape's border to that pixel. It can be computed in both directions outwards or inwards into the shape.
In this problem, the outward distance map suffices.

- Step 1: Compute the distance map of both shapes D_S1, D_S2
- Step 2: Subtract the distance maps. Diff = D_S1-D_S2
- Step 3: if Diff has only positive values. Then your shapes can be contained in each other(+ve => S1 bigger than S2 -ve => S2 bigger than S1)
  If the Diff has both positive and negative values, the shapes intersect.

There you have it. Enjoy !

Comment: maybe it wasn't clear in the question, but the question allows rotating or translation of the objects